# How to pass test configuration parameters to 'Call to Test' in HP ALM

Tags: test-design, quality-center, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

When you create test steps with parameters in test instance you can set up several test configurations (to run the same test with different set of parameters).

[image: 3 sets of params]

Test instance with params (and sets of params) could be used in another test instance as "Call to Test" (If it's marked as test template). But it looks like there is only one fixed set of params for 'Called Test'

[image: params in 'Call to Test']

The task is to pass params from calling test's "Test Configuration" to the called test. Is it possible?

**P.S.:** till now the best solution I have is to copy test steps and not to call it, but it will not be possible to edit these substeps just in one place any more (as they are not substeps but steps as it is). You will have to change them in every test instance they are used in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple: you need to leave `Called Test` parameters empty so they would be marked with `?` symbol in call step. Have a look at this:

[image: Call to Test with empty parameter]

```
 Call <Expert Parameter - controlTrafficNetworkType> with the following parameters: network type = ?
```

So when you create the new test configuration (param/value pairs) there will be desired parameter from `Called Test`

**EDIT**

**N.B.:** Default values are not implemented by default. After test instance creation you still need to copy Default values in every test configuration data where it's supposed (You can select all the params holding `Ctrl` pressed and copy all the values at a time).

[image: Copy default values button] Copy Default Values button